# Reconciling Liouville’s theorem and Dirichlet's theorem

Tags: real-analysis, diophantine-approximation

Liouville’s approximation theorem (at least, in the form I've seen expressed in several sources after a quick Google search, for instance [this](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Rational_approximation#Liouville_Approximation_Theorem) and [this](http://www.math.niu.edu/courses/math421/liouville.pdf)) states that if $\alpha$ is an algebraic number of degree $d \geq 2$, then there is a constant $c=c(\alpha)$ such that $$\left|\alpha - \frac{p}{q}\right| > \frac{c(\alpha)}{q^d}$$

for all rational $\frac{p}{q}$. This seems to be equivalent to the claim that there are only finitely many  rational $\frac{p}{q}$ obeying $$\left|\alpha - \frac{p}{q}\right| \leq \frac{1}{q^d}$$

On the other hand, Dirichlet's approximation theorem asserts that for any irrational $\alpha$, there are infinitely many rational $\frac{p}{q}$ satisfying $$\left|\alpha- \frac{p}{q}\right| \leq \frac{1}{q^2}$$

These two theorems seem to be flatly contradictory in the situation that $\alpha$ is an algebraic irrational number of degree $2$ (say, $\alpha=\sqrt{2}$). What explains this discrepancy? Or is the statement of Liouville's theorem above in fact incorrect, and we require that $d \geq 3$?

Comment: There's no contradiction if $c(\alpha) \lt  1$. The first two inequalities in your question are not equivalent.

Comment: @Sam I can believe that. So would the formulation of the theorem [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LiouvillesApproximationTheorem.html) and [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Rational_approximation#Liouville_Approximation_Theorem) be incorrect? In the Wolfram link, they explicitly say that they are equivalent, but having thought about it I'm inclined to agree with you that they aren't equivalent.

Comment: Notice the Wolfram link requires $d \gt 2$. The article in the other link is missing that condition (clearly a typo, since it has the correct statement in a previous corollary)